# Accessing an imported element after the original DOMDocument is destroyed

Tags: php, html, html-parsing, domdocument, xmlnode

I've been messing around with DOMDocument lately, and I've noticed that in order to transfer elements from one document to the next, I have to call [`$DOMDocument->importNode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.importnode.php) on the target `DOMDocument`.

However, I'm running into weird issues, where once the originating document is destroyed, the cloned element misbehaves.

---

For example, here's some lovely working code:

```php
$dom1 = new DOMDocument;
$dom2 = new DOMDocument;

$dom2->loadHTML('<div id="div"><span class="inner"></span></div>');
$div = $dom2->getElementById('div');

$children = $dom1->importNode( $div, true )->childNodes;

echo $children->item(0)->tagName; // Output: "span"
```

Here's a demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/pjd9Ty

---

The problem arises when I try using the elements after their original document is out of scope:

```php
global $dom;
$dom = new DOMDocument;

function get_div_children () {

    global $dom;

    $local_dom = new DOMDocument;
    $local_dom->loadHTML('<div id="div"><span class="inner"></span></div>');

    $div = $local_dom->getElementById('div');

    return $dom->importNode( $div, true )->childNodes;
}

echo get_div_children()->item(0)->tagName;
```

The above results in the following errors:

> **PHP Warning**: Couldn't fetch `DOMElement`. Node no longer exists in ...
>   **PHP Notice**: Undefined property: `DOMElement::$tagName` in ...

Here's a demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/c0kqOA

---

My question is twofold:

1. Shouldn't the returned elements exist even after the original document was destroyed, since they were cloned into the current document?
2. A workaround. For various reasons, I have to manipulate the elements after the original document is destroyed, but before I actually insert them into the DOM of the other `DOMDocument`. Is there any way to accomplish this?

---

**Clarification:** I understand that if the elements are inserted into the DOM, it behaves as expected. But, as outlined above, my setup calls for the elements to be manipulated before being inserted into the DOM (long story). Given that the first example here works - and that manipulating elements outside of the DOM is standard procedure in JavaScript - shouldn't this be possible here as well?

Comment: It's not happening because `$local_dom` is being destroyed. There is some other problem going on. See [this demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/XcQNCH), where I set both DOM objects to be global, and the problem still happens.

Comment: @nickb +1 Wow! That's *really* weird. It basically does the exact same thing as the function-less code. For a second there I thought it might have something to do with the original `$div` element being destroyed, but [making *that* global doesn't either help](http://codepad.viper-7.com/yH4liF). Any idea how to attack this?

Comment: Here's [another example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/iL0lh3); it's still scope related somehow, but even `unset($local_dom)` [can't simulate it](http://codepad.viper-7.com/R6PObg).

Comment: @Jack - Yep. This is just getting weirder by the minute. I'm afraid I'll have no other choice but to rewrite this huge class of mine, so that the elements being passed around are always within the DOM :(

Answer (score 0):

The cloned node has a reference to $dom, but $dom has not. Internal PHP garbage collector destroys such nodes when the calling context changes. There is only one way to create this reference: `$dom->documentElement->appendChild($node)`.

So, use code like this (static keyword will prevent garbage collector from destroying your variable):

```
global $dom;
$dom = new DOMDocument;

function get_div_children () {

global $dom;

$local_dom = new DOMDocument;
$local_dom->loadHTML('<div id="div"><span class="inner"></span></div>');

$div = $local_dom->getElementById('div');
static $nodes;
$nodes = $dom->importNode( $div, true )->childNodes;
return $nodes;
}

echo get_div_children()->item(0)->tagName;
```